# Confusing Answer with comment in Audit leads to acceptable answer being used as a fail-test for an audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

As described in the title, I got an answer while reviewing low quality posts that didn't seem particularly low quality to me, but it had odd comments on it so I was a bit confused. I marked it as OK because it looked OK but [I failed the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18800692). I believe that there was a poor answer there before it was edited at a point, but I'm not certain of it? This entire scenario is confusing. Included are pictures of the post

Is this a particularly bad answer, and what am I to do with the bizarre comments that seem unrelated to anything?

Here is the audit as a screenshot for the 10k challenged:
[image]

Comment: "so I was a bit confused" whenever you are confused, skip. There's no shame in skipping, and other reviewers who understand what is at hand without becoming confused will review it later.

Comment: You should be linking to the actual audit, not just posting screenshots.

Comment: @Servy Sorry about that I edited it into the question.

Comment: Wait, so there's a link saying "please stop linking to a porn site" and this made you do NOTHING with it? not even look at the links or anything? That feels like a..... suboptimal review :/ (in other words: the audit seems to have done its job if even with hints about what the problem is, you still made the mistake)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The post is spam.  It's linking to a porn site.  The edit to the post is editing the spam *into* the post, not out of it (in an attempt to avoid detection).  It's also pretty much just a copy paste of the accepted answer, but with the porn link edited in.

Of course the comments even tell you all of this, so you merely needed to check if they were correct (something that can be done merely by hovering over the link, and looking at the other answer to the question).  Not only did you not do this before marking the post as okay, you didn't even go back and double check this *after* failing the audit, or before posting here on meta.

This is exactly the type of bad content that we expect reviewers to be able to find when reviewing, meaning it's a great audit.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that link. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @EliSadoff Well you read the comment telling you exactly what I already told you.